# Is there any way to write a few bytes to a disk sector without reading it first?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I've been experimenting with the performance of reading and writing files on Linux, specifically O_DIRECT, and I'm wondering, both at a hard drive level and the posix/Linux API level, is it possible to write only a few bytes to a sector, without destroying the rest of the sector, and without reading it first?

Comment: As far as I know, all disk I/O is block-based and has to be done one block at a time.

Comment: In general, no, as drives are block devices; however I wouldn't find it extremely surprising if certain drives that have custom firmware for use in specific high-end RAID arrays or something allowed partial writes from the host end that then do the read-modify-write cycle entirely on the disk controller. But I'm not directly aware of any such drives, either.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly, and why?

Comment: Why do you ask? What do you expect the unwritten part of the updated sector to contain (all zeros, or the previous contents)? And on real hard disks (not SSDs) the latency is so huge that you should not matter write a whole sector....

Comment: No, not with any standard drive.  The entire sector must be written at once, both because you can't turn on/off writing with the necessary precision to do otherwise, and because the CRC at the end of the sector must be rewritten to take into account the new bytes.

Comment: Its really not possible practically. Because all HDDs have some sort of a buffer memory between the computer and the storage disk. Unless you write a custom firmware for HDD, forget bypassing the HDD buffer.And there are those HDD specific technology stuff, that make it harder to have more control on how you do the I/O on that drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience with disk drives is that they expect data to be sent to them in entire sectors. So, basically, there's no way of writing less than an entire sector and if you wish to change the start of a sector without changing the end, you **must** read the whole sector, modify and write back. That is partly to do with how the disk head interacts with the platter (for physical disks anyway. In the case of flash drives, it's more likely to be with how small a chunk of the flash can be erased in one go).

Answer (score 0):

In a portable way? Probably not.

In Linux and a few other Unix-like systems, you can open the block device for the drive, seek to a position (probably aligned to the sector size) and write some data to it, but I don't know what effect it would have on the remaining portion of that block.

Your best bet is to try it out on a virtual machine and see what happens. (Obviously, you'll have to have permission to write to the block device.)

Comment: You probably still have to to write a full sector (or some multiple of it).

Comment: That's probably device and implementation specific. I'd bet that unaligned reads/writes are fixed up on-the-fly, padded out with filler, or otherwise emulated as a read/write cycle at the controller or drive level.